Man steals gold bars and melts it into a boat structure
Does anybody know what kind of movie this is? 
I do not remember a lot of it, but the main plot was about a guy who stole many gold bars and melted it into a boat structure. There was a lot of doubleplay, where one guy suddenly change side and try to steal the gold, then he is on the other side, and work with the other people.

Hrm. Quite a few similarities to The Italian Job, with Matt Damon and Edward Norton.

Is it Heist? It's not with Boats, but still, seems that the idea is the same.

@Larme It is a boat in Heist and in fact that's what I immediately thought when reading the question title only.

@JohnP Matt Damon isn't in The Italian Job, you're probably after Mark Wahlberg.

Diabolik from Danger: Diabolik melted tons of gold that he had stolen and smuggled underwater.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger:_Diabolik

@ChristianRau - You're right, I knew that. Thinking of Rounders for some reason.

This sounds pretty much like Heist, whose plot summary suggests a whole lot of doubleplay going on:

David Mamet takes this story of thieves along many twists and turns,
  some of which work and some of which don't. Gene Hackman plays the
  brilliant leader of a gang (Delroy Lindo, Ricky Jay & Rebecca Pigeon
  as Hackman's youngish wife), which pulls off complex heists for a
  despicable fence (Danny DeVito). After stiffing the gang on a jewelry
  robbery, DeVito forces the gang to go after a Swiss gold shipment and
  to use his nephew (Sam Rockwell) in the crime. No one trusts anyone
  and every step is shaded with the unexpected.

Near the end there is a scene where it is revealed that the railing of Gene Hackman's character's boat is made out of the melted and reformated gold (though that isn't the end of the story either, I think).

You're not thinking of Die Hard 4.0 are you? The antagonist steals a whole lot of gold and appears to load it on a boat which he then sinks, saying the rich have too much and the poor don't have anything. It turned out though, he hadn't actually put the gold on the boat, but had secretly absconded with it.

You're talking about Die Hard 3, or to be exact, Die Hard with a Vengeance, not Die Hard 4.0. But it doesn't fit too well anyway.

Sorry haha, mixed up.
